# Represent the given signal in mathematical form

Tags: signal-theory

[image]

Is this the mathematical form? I highy doubt myself

[image]

$$
-2r(t+3)+2r(t)+16u(t)-r(t)-2u(t-3)+5/2r(t-3)-5/2r(t-5)
$$

Comment: Any chance you can rotate the image or, better still, type it in?

Comment: it looks like a sum of a sawtooth wave, a square wave and an offset

Comment: Is this a transfer function or a time series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the horizontal axis by time t and vertical axis by signal value x(t).

From t=-3 to t=3 the first part you wrote
$$ x(t) = -2 r(t+3) + 2 r(t) + 16 u(t) - r(t) - 2 u(t-3) $$
is correct.

From t=0 to t=3, the signal x(t) above is sloping down with \$\frac {dx(t)}{dt} = \frac{7-10}{3-0} = -1\$.
According to given graph, this slope should become \$\frac {dx(t)}{dt} = \frac{0-5}{5-3}= -2.5\$, so, a ramp giving a slope of -3/2 should be added.
$$ x(t) = \bigg( -2 r(t+3) + 2 r(t) + 16 u(t) - r(t) - 2 u(t-3) \bigg) - \frac{3}{2} r(t-3) $$

To compensate after t=5, the slope of -2.5 should be nullified:
$$ x(t) = \bigg( -2 r(t+3) + 2 r(t) + 16 u(t) - r(t) - 2 u(t-3) - \frac{3}{2} r(t-3) \bigg) + \frac{5}{2} r(t-5)$$

Comment: I verified these equations using LTspice (but, still, do double check). If you are familiar with LTspice, I'm happy to share the circuit.

Comment: Any motivation for the -1 vote? Is my math incorrect or the explanation?

Comment: People like dv here

Comment: @P__J__ If only we could downvote downvotes: *This downvote does not show any effort; it is unclear or not useful*

Comment: DVs should not be anonymous.

Comment: I have many "followers" on the SO who DV all of my answers :). When I wrote what I think about it - I was banned for 3 months. So actually I have decided to not waste my time and to stop answer questions

Comment: @P__J__ I agree, but this shouldn't discussed here... Moreover, I don't care for reputation numbers , still I want to know if and how I should improve the answer.

Comment: @Huisman I also get that regularly. In my case I have identified the principal individual. (Once you have a hypothesis of whom, you can see the -1 hit they take and approximately when, which then provides the exact confirmation.) Like you, I don't care for the rep numbers. But I also would very much like to hear from this individual about their reasoning (other than just mean-spiritedness.) If I could find a way to incorporate their thoughts or troubles without sacrificing my own goals, I might try.